# Cannot read property 'title' of null 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made addNotes function and it worked perfectly. Then , i also made remove function which worked fine but after sometime i am getting this error for both add and remove functions.

app.js - https://pastebin.com/ymeQ2zAX

```
yargs.command({
command : 'add',
describe : ':adds a new note',
builder: {
    title: {
        describe: 'note it down',
        demandOption: true,
        type: 'string'
    },
    body: {
        describe: 'describe the note',
        type:'string'
    }
},
handler : function(argv) {
    notes.addNotes(argv.title,argv.body)
}
})
```

notes.js - https://pastebin.com/VQjtWZNC

```
const addNotes=function(title,body)
{
const notes=loadNotes()
var k=0
for(var i=0;i<notes.length;i++)
{
    if(title===notes[i].title) k=1
}
if(k===0)
{
    notes.push({
        title: title,
        body: body
    })
    saveNotes(notes)
    console.log(chalk.green.bold("New Note Added!"))
}
else{
    console.log(chalk.red.bold("Title already there"))
} 
}
```

Comment: delete will only set the index to empty (deleting the reference), and will not resize the array to remove the element.  You either need to add handling of empty indexes in your for loops iterating over the array of notes, or use `notes.splice(i,1)` instead of `delete notes[i]` to fully remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `delete notes[i]`, which makes `notes[i]` return undefined, but the length of x is not changed, so when you use your for-loop to iterate over it, you iterate on `undefined` at the deleted index.  Fix at bottom.

`delete` removes the property from the object.  What this means for arrays, is that the object at the integer index (property) is removed from the array object, but the underlying array's length does not change.
If you use `for-in` or `in` or `hasOwnProperty(index)` it will treat that array index (property) as not existing, but the underlying array has a gap where the index was deleted and so accessing the deleted index returns undefined.

It's important to note that this is different than having `undefined` as a value at the deleted index.  It is actually an empty reference and behaves like accessing a non-existing property on an object.
For example, `delete x[3]` and `x[3]=undefined` are different, where the main practical difference is that if you use something like `for-of` or `forEach` to iterate over the array, it will skip over index 3 if you use `delete x[3]`, whereas if you use `x[3]=undefined` it will still iterate over index 3 with a value of undefined.

See [Deleting array Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

> When you delete an array element, the **array length is not affected**. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

> When the delete operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array. In the following example, trees[3] is removed with delete.

```
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
delete trees[3];
if (3 in trees) {
    // this is not executed
}
```

> If you want an array element to exist but have an undefined value, use the undefined value instead of the delete operator. In the following example, trees[3] is assigned the value undefined, but the array element still exists:

```
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees[3] = undefined;
if (3 in trees) {
    // this is executed
}
```

> If instead, you want to remove an array element by changing the contents of the array, use the splice() method. In the following example, trees[3] is removed from the array completely using splice():

```
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees.splice(3,1);
console.log(trees); // ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", "maple"]
```

```js
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];

console.log(trees, trees.length, 3 in trees);

delete trees[3];

console.log(trees, trees.length, 3 in trees); // empty reference 3, 3 in trees is false

trees[3] = undefined;

console.log(trees, trees.length, 3 in trees); // 3 in trees is true

trees.splice(3,1);

console.log(trees, trees.length, 3 in trees)
// notice index 3 is gone and the length is now one less
```

---

To fix your code

On line 36:

```
     if(title===notes[i].title) delete notes[i]
```

Change to:

```
     if(title===notes[i].title) notes.splice(i,1)
```